# The rails params are not symbolized

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
def log_experiments
     => 23:   binding.pry
        24:   logger.debug "Experiment: 'navigation_location': '#{navigation_location_experiment}'"
        25: end


[1] pry(#<MainController>)> params
=> {"sub_category1"=>"shoes", "controller"=>"main", "action"=>"index"}
[2] pry(#<MainController>)>
```

How and where can I check what is wrong here? by default the param keys should be symbolized...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Params use a special type of hash - hash with indifferent access. Elements of such hashes can be accessed both by symbols and string. For printing hash the default form is string.
Look at rails reference -  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html This is doc for rails 4.0, but the previous versions have the same